# Is there a more reliable cp and mv which verifies the file and / or folder transferred to be identical? (such as by rsync?)

Tags: rsync, cp, mv, file-transfer

Is there a way to use `cp` and / or `mv` so that it verifies the files to be identical.  This is especially true for `mv`, which would remove the original file, so if the destination file is corrupted, then the data could be lost forever.

And this may happen when we are less aware of it, such as when we drag and drop the file over from one file manager window to another, and think everything is fine.

Can we do it in a series of commands, such as

```
cp file01.dat /Volumes/storage01/file01.dat && __________  # the verification
```

However, since the command could be executed as "executed this command" of a 3rd party program, the commands need to handle that properly as well (cannot rely on an error message printed to the user, because the user cannot see it).

Can `rsync` verify the file to have been transferred properly?  What's more, since the cache in RAM may say that data in the destination file is `02 fc 3a` but on the hard drive, it is corrupted as `00 00 00`, so can the verification disable the RAM cache of the destination file if possible?

Comment: You didn't provide any of the requested information on the [question you mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441106/how-to-avoid-macos-copying-a-file-and-the-file-is-different-from-the-original).This question might help: [Is there a copy-and-verify command in Ubuntu/Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/218544/is-there-a-copy-and-verify-command-in-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: they were asking for the file type and the app to open the file.  Well, does it really matter?  My file can be `file01.dat` and it is full of scientific data. It can be comma separated number in it. But does it really matter?  If the `diff` doesn't pass, what is there more to say?

Comment: If the file on disk differs from the cached version in RAM then you have bigger problems than just verifying a cp or rsync.  That should not happen...and if it does, it means you probably have some kind of hardware fault - maybe faulty RAM, dying disk, bad cables, unreliable power supply, etc.   The correct solution is to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: if you're mounting a remote filesystem, the TCP layer is in charge of making sure the data arrives intact and in order. each computer is in charge of taking data between disk and network. you have three possible failure points: the source computer, the destination computer, and the network

Answer (score 1):

***rsync*** doesn't require anything special to do this. From the man page:

> *Note that rsync always verifies* that each transferred file was
> correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-file
> checksum that is generated as the file is transferred.

This is different from the -c or --checksum option, which uses checksums to see if only a part of a file needs to be transferred, rather than the complete file.

You should be able to set up *rsync* to run locally, over a network, or by appearing to be local while running over a network through an SSH tunnel.

Just as a file copy can fail due to disk corruption, etc, generation of a checksum from a file could fail for the same reason, ie due to a bad disk read. So nothing is ever perfect.

Comment: I suppose a command or an app can do this: copy the file over, and now use the system call to read in the file and select to disable any cache, or be able to clear all cache so the data is read directly from the hard drive. From this compare, if everything checks, then this is closer to perfect. But I know, just utter the words "nothing is perfect" and now you are the master of the universe

Comment: Note that the checksum verification only verifies that files were correctly transferred, it doesn’t verify that they were correctly written.

Comment: so ideally, to verify the file has been properly written, we need to either somehow disable or empty the cache, or turn off the Mac or PC and the NAS, and then turn them back on so there is no data from the cache in RAM, and now do a diff to verify the data directly read from the hard drive?

Comment: Nothing is ever perfect, but some things are less risky. Adding a checksum should reduce the risk of failure quite a bit. If the risk of cp corrupting the file is say 0.001 and the risk of an incorrect checksum is also 0.001, then the risk of both failing for the same file is 0.000001.

Comment: Factor in the chance that an incorrect checksum happens to be the same as the original checksum, and you’ve virtually ruled out failure.